# как преобразовать id в строку java android

Tags: java, строки, типы-данных

Имеется массив картинок `buts[]` из 10 штук. Хотелось бы с помощью цикла `for` укоротить код, чтобы не повторять этот отрезок 10 раз. Не получается преобразовать результат  от `get.id` в строку формата "R.id.imageviewi"

```
for (i=0; i<10;i++){
    if (v.getId()==R.id.imageView**0**){
        if (!player) {
            buts[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.krest);
            player = true;
            result1 = 1;
         } else if (player) {
            buts[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.nol);
            player = false;
            result1 = 0;
         }
         buts[0].setClickable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, вам надо было гуглить вот так

> [get resource id by name android](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=get%20resource%20id%20by%20name%20android)

вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476470/3212712):

```
//под 'this' надо понимать `Context` - т.е., например, активити
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("ИМЯ_РЕСУРСА_В_ВИДЕ_СТРОКИ", "id", this.getPackageName());
```

Т.е. в вашем случае должно быть как-то так:

```
if (v.getId() == getResources().getIdentifier("imageView"+String.valueOf(i), "id", getPackageName()))
```